# Selenium - How to navigate multiple nested framesets and frames

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following frameset structure.
I want to make "main" the active frame. The documentation on the Selenium site on how to do this is very limited. I have seen quite a few examples that do the following for nested frames and such like `driver.switchTo().frame("a.b.c.d");` but some of my frames are nameless. So how would I go about getting the the "main" frame?

[image]

Comment: you need to switch frame - `driver.switchTo()...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use: driver.switchTo().frame(int frameIndex)

Comment: Tried that. Whenever I specified frame 1 or 2 its would say it cant find the frame. Solved this issue by finding the frame by id and using the Frame WebElement as an argument.

Comment: Besides, adding another frame might break finding by index

Answer (score 0):

Find the frame element using driver.findElement and then use driver.switchTo.frame(foundWebElement);